# Refresh JWT token without redux and use context

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt, react-context

I use react with redux and use JWT token to authentication users, JWT has short life time and I wrote a middleware to refresh token like as below:

```
import { refreshToken, refreshTokenFail } from '../actions/index';

const jwtTokenRefresh = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
        const timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        const expiration = getState().auth.expiration;
        if (expiration && timeStamp > expiration && !getState().auth.refreshToken) {
            return refreshToken(dispatch)
                .then(() => {
                    return next(action)
                }).catch(() => {
                    console.log('fail')
                    dispatch(refreshTokenFail(dispatch)).then(() =>{
                        window.location.href= "/login";
                    })
                });
        }
    }

    return next(action);
};

export default jwtTokenRefresh;
```

But now I want write new react app without redux and using from `react context`, how can I refresh token in react context?

Comment: You can set this code inside service-worker

Comment: @Masoud92m It depends a bit on the http client you plan on using. With axios for example you can handle all 401 Unauthorized responses by refreshing the token. I would separate this concern from React btw (API authentication vs. view rendering).